# Add xmlns attribute & validate schema programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I'm validating an XML document against a schema that might not include the xmlns:information within it. So, how do I flag such a document (or any node that doesn't have that schema information) as invalid? I'm asking because .NET only lets you validate against schemas that have been properly identified in the XML document and I want to guarantee that no XML gets through that doesn't comply with the schema.

**How exactly do I validate this schema without needing to add the attributes, save the file, and reload it?**

For example, this works:

```
        xmlDoc.Load(file);

        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://test.mysite.com/schemas/myschemas");
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:schemaLocation", "schemas/myschema.xsd");

        xmlDoc.Save(file);  

        XmlSchema mySchema = XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader.Create("schemas/myschema.xsd"), settings_ValidationEventHandler);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.Schemas.Add(mySchema);
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(settings_ValidationEventHandler);

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file, settings);
        xmlDoc.Load(reader);
```

But this does not:

```
        xmlDoc.Load(file);

        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://test.mysite.com/schemas/myschemas");
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:schemaLocation", "schemas/myschema.xsd");

        XmlSchema mySchema = XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader.Create("schemas/myschema.xsd"), settings_ValidationEventHandler);

        xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(mySchema);

        xmlDoc.Validate(settings_ValidationEventHandler);
```

Comment: Definite duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-validation?sort=faq

Comment: My question relates specifically to dynamically adding the xmlns attribute to a document so that I can validate against an arbitrary schema. I can't find a post that addresses that issue.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't quite make sense. Which `xmlns` attribute do you think you have to add? And what sense does it make to validate against an "arbitrary" schema? It only makes sense to validate a document against the schemas which define it.

Comment: Yeah, but the only way I've been able to successfully validate an xml file against a schema is if the schema has been indicated in the xml file itself. I'd like to look at any xml file that I receive and validate it against my schema to ensure that I'm not getting junk.

Comment: That's your confusion. Most XML documents do not show the location of the schema inside themselves. You just have to know which schemas to use. The `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes are just a hint. Many XML processors totally ignore those.

Comment: Why don't my xml files validate (even when I know they are valid) unless I specify the xmlns and the location? That's why I had to add the attributes dynamically and then resave the files. What am I missing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21542/discussion-between-elucid8-and-john-saunders)